# Convergence of a sequence function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the sequence of function $F_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{z^n-3^n},\
>  n=1,2,...,\ $ converges to zero for $|z|<3$ amd to $1$ for $|z|>3$.

How can I show this? I can see why it will converge to zero when $|z|<3$, but can't see why it converges to $1$ when $|z|>3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{z^n}{z^n-3^n}=1+\frac{3^n}{z^n-3^n}=\begin{cases}1+\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)^n\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{3}{z}\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1+0\cdot\frac{1}{1-0}=1\;,\;\;|z|>3\\{}\\1-\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1-\frac{1}{1-0}=0\;,\;\;|z|<3\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks Don! One question, when you have these types of problems do you have to seperate it like you did into two different equations?

Comment: @Q.matin, it is advisable to do so to see things clearer (at least for me), but I guess you don't *have to* if you don't want and can manage otherwise.

Comment: Understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: 
$$F_n(z) = \bigg({z \over 3}\bigg)^n {1  \over \big({z \over 3}\big)^n - 1} = {1 \over 1 - \big({3 \over z}\big)^n}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$\left|F(z)-1\right|=\left|\frac{3^n}{z^n-3^n}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{(z/3)^n-1}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\left|\,|z/3|^n-1\,\right|}$$ and since $|z|>3$ then $\lim_n \left|z/3\right|^n=\infty$ then $\lim_n F(z)=1$.